# How to find ArcGIS iOS AGSPoint xy coordinates with latitude and longitude?

Tags: ios, arcgis

I am creating a wayfinding app that will display directions based on the device's current location and desired destination. I am trying to add stop points. How would I find the x and y values of the AGSPoint given the latitude and longitude of the location? I found the following code after doing some research, but the compiler tells me that * is not a prefix unary operator

```
     func findAGSPointXY(longitude:Double, latitude:Double) -> (){
    let mercatorX = longitude * 0.017453292519943295 * 6378137.0;
    let a = latitude * 0.017453292519943295;
    let mercatorY = 3189068.5 * log((1.0 + sin(a))/(1.0 - sin(a)));
    AGSPoint *graphicPoint = [AGSPoint pointWithX:mercatorX y:mercatorY spatialReference:[AGSSpatialReference wgs84SpatialReference]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing objective-c and swift, there are objc pointers (*), objc methods call ([]) and swift const (let) in the same snippet. I assume you're using swift.

The ArcGIS SDK can reproject geometries, you don't have to compute theses values by hand.

```
//Create an AGSPoint from your parameters, specifying them as WGS 84.
let wgsPoint = AGSPoint(x: longitude, y: latitude, spatialReference:  AGSSpatialReference.wgs84())

//Preparing a Geometry Engine
let geometryEngine = AGSGeometryEngine.defaultGeometryEngine()

//Get a projected (in web mercator) geometry (points, lines, polygons and whatever inherit AGSGeometry).
let projGeometry = geometryEngine.projectGeometry(wgsPoint, toSpatialReference: AGSSpatialReference.webMercatorSpatialReference())
//Cast it back to AGSPoint, might have some optional to manage
let projPoint = projGeometry as AGSPoint // Might be some optional to manage there

//Here you can use projPoint.x and projPoint.y
```